# Colorbox make 2 div in DOM

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Since I updated colobox to 1.4.15, I've an issue :

In DOM I've got 2 div with id="colorbox", one is hidden, the other one is visible :

The hidden one :

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
<div id="cboxWrapper">
<div>
<div id="cboxTopLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxTopCenter" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxTopRight" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left;">
<div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left;"></div>
<button id="cboxPrevious" type="button"></button>
<button id="cboxNext" type="button"></button>
<button id="cboxSlideshow"></button>
<div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left;"></div>
<button id="cboxClose" type="button"></button>
<div id="cboxLikes" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
<div id="cboxBottomLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxBottomCenter" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxBottomRight" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

The visible one

```
<div id="colorbox" class="cboxSlideshow_off" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 117px; left: 32px; position: absolute; width: 1200px; height: 631px;">
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 631px; width: 1200px;">
<div>
<div style="clear: left;">
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 564px;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 858px; height: 564px;">
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 858px; overflow: auto; height: 536px;">
<div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left; display: block;">LAN'Oween 2013</div>
<div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left; display: block;">Image 1 sur 36</div>
<button id="cboxPrevious" type="button" style="display: block;">Précédante</button>
<button id="cboxNext" type="button" style="display: block;">Suivante</button>
<button id="cboxSlideshow" style="display: block;">Démarrer le diaporama</button>
<div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<button id="cboxClose" type="button">Fermer</button>
</div>
<div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 564px;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
<div id="cboxBottomLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
<div id="cboxBottomCenter" style="float: left; width: 858px;"></div>
<div id="cboxBottomRight" style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The init :

```
    $("a.lightbox").colorbox(
    {
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        slideshowAuto: false,
        slideshowStart: "Démarrer le diaporama",
        slideshowStop: "Arrêter le diaporama",
        current: "Image {current} sur {total}",
        previous: "Précédante",
        next: "Suivante",
        close: "Fermer",
        maxWidth: "95%",
        maxHeight: "95%",
        rel: 'teamzerty'
    }
   );
```

The problem is that I can't manipulate the box.

I'm using :
- JQuery 2.0.0
- JQuery UI 1.10.3
- colobox 1.4.15

Thank's for help.

Exemple : http://www.team-azerty.com/html/lan/lan-galerie-59-lan-oween-2013.html

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever use an ID once in your DOM - if you find yourself needing to use it more than once, consider changing it to a class instead of an ID! If you try to use an ID more than once it won't work correctly.